# Maximum close price pinescript tradingview

Tags: pine-script, trading

Is there a way to get the maximum close price of last 200 candles of 15 min ?

Answer (score 0):

```
maxClose = highest(close, 200)
```

The code above finds the highest close of the last 200 candles for the current timeframe you're in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MTF oscillator framework [PineCoders]](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Wvcqygsx-MTF-Oscillator-Framework-PineCoders/) and apply the answer of @bbnm

```
i_htf        = input(defval = "15" , title = "Select Higher Timeframe", type = input.resolution)

maxClose15   = security(syminfo.tickerid, i_htf,
               highest(close, 200)[1],
               lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)//No repaint
```